# Creating a user in the standard users folder using command line (Windows Server 2012)

Tags: server, active-directory, command, command-prompt

**Information**

Let's say that I have a server on the domain "domain.com". In the active directory, I have the OU Finance, in that OU, I have the OU Users.

If I want to create a user in this folder, using command line it would be:

```
dsadd user CN=user01,OU=Users,OU=Finance,DC=domain,DC=com
```

This is excluding the parameters of course.

**Question**

Every server has a "Users" folder, which contains the standard-users such as the Administrator.

How would I create a user in that standard folder, using the commandline? And how would I add that user to a group that is inside of the "Built-in" folder?

Let's say that the username would be user01 and the group "Administrators"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that the built-in Users folder isn't an OU, it's a "Container" (i.e. the `objectClass` is "container" rather than "organizationalUnit"). So the distinguished name of that container is prefixed by `CN=` rather than `OU=`.

So try this:

```
dsadd user CN=user01,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com
```

Comment: Is this the same with the "Builtin" OU or container? If I'd like to add the user to a group, do I use: -memberof CN=Administrators,CN=Builtin,DC=domain,DC=com

Comment: Yes, exactly. In AD Users and Computers, in the properties of any object, you should see an 'Attribute Editor' tab. Look up the `distinguishedName` there. Whatever that is is what you need to use.